# Do game programming just let all the objects in the program to interact with themselves and what about preventing infinite loop?

Tags: game-loop, objects

Does game programming use the method of

1) using time as the main controller to let objects interact with each other, so each step, let 1 object send messages to `N` objects, and the second object to any number of objects, and 3rd, 4th, until all objects done, and that's it, and display the results on screen (or think of it as just a loop that always repeat, with each iteration considered "a tick in time")    (so object 1 call object 2's method, and object 2 cannot call other object's method immediately?  otherwise, there can be infinite loop like (2) below.  but how do you implement: "cannot call other objects until next time?" )

Or,

2) let the objects freely call other objects' methods (send messages to them), with no "Time" concept like the above

Are they both feasible solutions?  But what if in (2), you have stones in a circular tube, and stone 1 pushes stone 2, and 2 pushes 3, and so forth, until stone N pushes stone 1 again, then the program will go into infinite loop and not able to do anything else (say if the program is a single process, single thread)

Comment: Both are probably used. Are you asking which one is 'better', for some value of better?

Comment: yeah, which one better, and how to prevent infinite loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually you have some separate class that does things like collision detection (collision-solver). So instead of *Object A sending a "collide" message to Object B*, you have a class that holds a list of all Objects. In one step (or update), the class checks collision for all objects in that list and stops when all objects have been checked.

With this setup it can still happen that if you move an object out of the way due to a collision, it will still collide with another object. To resolve this issue you can iterate the collision-solver several times within one update loop. As long as you have a specialized class that does this, the number of iterations can easily be controlled and infinite loops can be avoided.

Comment: hm, can it be `Object` class having collision detection so a basket ball, grass, tree, all inherit from the Object class and have this capability?  This may feel more object oriented as in the real world, atoms repel themselves, not by another class.

Comment: While it might feel more *natural* to let every object handle its collision by itself it's probably not very efficient. Your objects *need* to be able to query the world somehow and they probably need some helper-class(es) to do that too. That means you'll have some data-structure that will allow you to query the world and you can use that for collision detection and other stuff just as well.